# Выделение строки в RichTextBox

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня в RichTextBox загружается текстовый log-файл. Мне нужно сделать: если встретится в файле ключевое слово "ERROR", то соответствующая строка должна быть выделена красным цветом. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для WPF:

А зачем вам целый `RichTextBox`? Вполне достаточно взять `TextBlock`.

Прочитайте текст построчно, найдите строки с ERROR, добавьте каждую в `Inlines`. В строчках с ERROR устанавливаете `Foreground`. Всё.

```
// модель
enum LineKind
{
    Default,
    Error
}

class Line
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public LineKind Kind { get; private set; }

    public Line(string text, LineKind kind) { Text = text; Kind = kind; }
}

IEnumerable<Line> ReadLines(string path)
{
    return File.ReadLines(path)
               .Select(text => new Line(text, Classify(text));
}

LineKind Classify(string text)
{
    return text.Contains("ERROR") ? LineKind.Error : LineKind.Default;
}

// бизнес-логику напишете сами

// представление
List<Line> allLines = await AsyncGetAllLines();
foreach (var line in allLines)
{
    var run = new Run(line.Text)
    {
        Foreground = GetForegroundForLineKind(line.Kind)
    };
    textblock.Inlines.Add(run);
    textblock.Inlines.Add(new Linebreak());
}

Brush GetForegroundForLineKind(LineKind kind)
{
    switch (kind)
    {
    case LineKind.Default: return Brushes.Black;
    case LineKind.Error: return Brushes.Red;
    default: throw new ArgumentException("unsupported line kind value: " + kind);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже надо только поочередно выделять ключевое слово и задавать ему цвет.

```
String searchString = "ERROR";  
int index = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(searchString, 16, 3);  
if (index != -1)  
    textBox1.Select(index, searchString.Length);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xc4fh98s(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Приведенный выше код работает только для проектов типа WindowsForms. А как быть, если тип проекта WPF? 